# Compiling error when reading array from file

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors

So when i go to compile my lab it says that `PrintSum(num)` the `num` is not initialized, but it shouldn't be because i'm using `num` to call a method. this is part of my program, if you can tell me what it's saying that, that would be great. I'm sure it's an easy fix and im just thinking too much into it.

```
    if(fileOpened&&inputFile.hasNext()){
      while(inputFile.hasNext()){
        if(inputFile.hasNextInt()){
          PrintSum(num);
          System.out.println("The sum of digits is " +PrintSum(num));
        }
        else
          inputFile.next();
      }
    }
  }
 //method to print sum of 2 digits   
  public static int PrintSum(int number){
    int result=0;
    while(number!=0){
      result=result+(number%10);
      number=number/10;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: If num is a local variable then it should be intialized before using. That is a java coding rule.

Comment: Instead of `int num;` use `int num = 0;` (`num` must have a value before any access to its value occurs).

Comment: **Unrelated**. In Java, method names by convention should start with lower case letter. Read this: [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 2):

If `num` is a method local variable then it should be initialized before using. That is a java coding rule.